# How to translate ts variables in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-translate

How to translate angular variables in template or ts file itself
  HTML code - someComponent.html

```
<button (click)="changeLang('en')">En</button>  
<button (click)="changeLang('de')">de</button>  
<p>{{rate}}</p>
```

Ts File - someComponent.ts

```
rate:string="productRate";
changeLang(lang){  
  this.translate.use(lang);
  this.traslate.get(this.rate).subscribe(res=>{this.rate = res;});
}
```

Json file-en.json

```
{ "productRate": "Product Rate" }
```

Json file-de.json

```
{ "productRate": "Produktpreis" }
```

I know how to do it in template using pipe but unable to do it in ts.
  I had referenced stack overflow but unable to get the result. Please help

Comment: Are you using a library ? If so, state this in your question

Comment: I am sorry for that. Yes I am using @ngx-translate/core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`Docs`](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods)

> get(key: string|Array, interpolateParams?: Object):
>   Observable: Gets the translated value of a key (or an
>   array of keys) or the key if the value was not found

You have to inject TranslateService as a dependency and do it as,

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    let foo:string = this.translate.get('productRate');
}
```

Comment: I injected the service sajeeth, to keep it simple I had posted without that.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: this.traslate.get('productRate').subscribe(res=>{this.rate = res;});  this will work. because translate.get returns observable.